# PHP - Calculating working hours between two dates but exclude the time when request is on hold

Tags: php, timestamp

Can some one help me write a function that calculates the number of working hours between two dates but want to exclude the time when the request had a status of "On Hold".

So lets say the request came in at 3PM friday and was closed at 3PM Wednesday, and working hours are from 8AM to 5PM pacific (Mon thru Friday)...Total working hours will be 27 hours...but if the request remained on hold from Monday 3PM till Tuesday 3PM...Actual work time on the request really becomes 18 hours instead of 27 hours.

I have recently started working on PHP and have been assigned this task which is very confusing to me. Please help

Comment: I think it's important to say how your data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get the total time elapsed, then substract the non-working hours.

You can use dateTime and [datePeriod](https://www.php.net/datePeriod) php objects for that  (requires php 5.3)

Here a small script to do what you want (but you will have probably to adapt for your needs)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

define('DAY_WORK', 32400); // 9 * 60 * 60
define('HOUR_START_DAY', '08:00:00');
define('HOUR_END_DAY', '17:00:00');
// get begin and end dates of the full period
$date_begin = '2013-11-29 15:00:00';
$date_end = '2013-12-03 15:00:00';

// keep the initial dates for later use
$d1 = new DateTime($date_begin);
$d2 = new DateTime($date_end);

// and get the datePeriod from the 1st to the last day
$period_start = new DateTime($d1->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
$period_end   = new DateTime($d2->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
//$interval = new DateInterval('weekdays'); // 1 day interval to get all days between the period
$period = new DatePeriod($period_start, $interval, $period_end);

$worked_time = 0;
$nb = 0;
// for every worked day, add the hours you want
foreach($period as $date){
  $week_day = $date->format('w'); // 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
  if (!in_array($week_day,array(0, 6)))
  {
    // if this is the first day or the last dy, you have to count only the worked hours 
    if ($date->format('Y-m-d') == $d1->format('Y-m-d'))
    {
        $end_of_day_format = $date->format('Y-m-d '.HOUR_END_DAY);
        $d1_format = $d1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $end_of_day = new DateTime($end_of_day_format);
        $diff = $end_of_day->diff($d1)->format("%H:%I:%S");
        $diff = split(':', $diff);
        $diff = $diff[0]*3600 + $diff[1]*60 + $diff[0];
        $worked_time += $diff;
    }
    else if ($date->format('Y-m-d') == $d2->format('Y-m-d'))
    {
        $start_of_day = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d '.HOUR_START_DAY));
        $d2_format = $d2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $end_of_day = new DateTime($end_of_day_format);
        $diff = $start_of_day->diff($d2)->format('%H:%I:%S');
        $diff = split(':', $diff);
        $diff = $diff[0]*3600 + $diff[1]*60 + $diff[0];
        $worked_time += $diff;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise, just count the full day of work
        $worked_time += DAY_WORK;
    }
  }
  if ($nb> 10)
    die("die ".$nb);
}
echo sprintf('Works from %s to %s, You worked %d hour(s)', $date_begin, $date_end, $worked_time/60/60);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So basically i will call this function twice to get the total working hours and then total hours on hold (after giving start and end date/time for the on hold time)...Minus it from total working hours and that should give me the actual time of the request, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "on hold time", but this code is simple : for each days, it adds the worked hours except if this is the 1st or the last day. If you want calculate other time, you can change that code to add others variables inside the proper if/else part, I m not sure calling it twice can do something. But to be sure, you can try it, and if that doesn't work for you, add some debug strings like `echo "so far, the ".$date->format('Y-m-d').", worked_time=$worked_time<br/>";` to see how the time is calculated.

Comment: bascially on hold is the time in which the request had not been worked on as more information was required on that. So I need to minus the on hold time from the total time. so let's say if a request start and end time is 20 hours and there was a 10 hour period in between where that request was on hold...total time will become total time = total time (start to end) minus on hold time.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate work time with an accuracy of 1 minute.

**WARNING: This function can take many seconds to load as it does a loop for every minute between the time span.**

```
<?php

$request = array(
    'start' => '3PM Nov 29 2013',
    'end' => '3PM Dec 4 2013'
);

echo calculate_work($request);

/**
 * Calculate work time by looping through every minute
 * @param  array $request start to end time
 * @return int  work time in minutes
 */
function calculate_work($request)
{
    $start = strtotime($request['start']);
    $end = strtotime($request['end']);
    $work_time = 0;

    /* Add 1 minute to the start so that we don't count 0 as a minute  */
    for ($time = $start + 60; $time <= $end; $time += 60)
    {
        // Weekends
        if (date('D', $time) == 'Sat' OR date('D', $time) == 'Sun')
            continue;

        // Non Working Hours
        if (date('Hi', $time) <= '0800' OR date('Hi', $time) > '1700')
            continue;

        // On Hold
        if ($time > strtotime('3PM Dec 2 2013') AND $time <= strtotime('3PM Dec 3 2013'))
            continue;

        $work_time++;
    }

    // Divide by 60 to turn minutes into hours
    return $work_time / 60;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this. I think **Asenar** answer is very close to what I was looking for

Comment: This function is actually very simple and cool. however it return 3 extra hours every time I run this. The above example should return 15 whereas it returns 18.

Comment: I fixed the function to return me the correct values. Basically you function was just missing "=" with greater than and less than signs. Now the only thing left, which is driving me crazy, is the logic to calculate minutes. Can you please guide me how to do that using your function?

Comment: I have updated the answer to calculate the minutes, but I don't understand why it should return 15 hours. I calculated 18 hours by hand and so did you in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * Get the total working hours in seconds between 2 dates..
 * @param DateTime $start Start Date and Time
 * @param DateTime $end Finish Date and Time
 * @param array $working_hours office hours for each weekday (0 Monday, 6 Sunday), Each day must be an array containing a start/finish time in seconds since midnight.
 * @return integer
 * @link https://github.com/RCrowt/working-hours-calculator
 */
function getWorkingHoursInSeconds(DateTime $start, DateTime $end, array $working_hours)
{
    $seconds = 0; // Total working seconds

    // Calculate the Start Date (Midnight) and Time (Seconds into day) as Integers.
    $start_date = clone $start;
    $start_date = $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp();
    $start_time = $start->getTimestamp() - $start_date;

    // Calculate the Finish Date (Midnight) and Time (Seconds into day) as Integers.
    $end_date = clone $end;
    $end_date = $end_date->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp();
    $end_time = $end->getTimestamp() - $end_date;

    // For each Day
    for ($today = $start_date; $today <= $end_date; $today += 86400) {

        // Get the current Weekday.
        $today_weekday = date('w', $today);

        // Skip to next day if no hours set for weekday.
        if (!isset($working_hours[$today_weekday][0]) || !isset($working_hours[$today_weekday][1])) continue;

        // Set the office hours start/finish.
        $today_start = $working_hours[$today_weekday][0];
        $today_end = $working_hours[$today_weekday][1];

        // Adjust Start/Finish times on Start/Finish Day.
        if ($today === $start_date) $today_start = min($today_end, max($today_start, $start_time));
        if ($today === $end_date) $today_end = max($today_start, min($today_end, $end_time));

        // Add to total seconds.
        $seconds += $today_end - $today_start;

    }

    return gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);

}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a big wall of code. Add some explanation to why it solves the problem, especially if its hard-to-read code. And please format it correctly.